# Recommendation for selection an administrative software

Tags: administration

I have a business were we sell automotive breakes, we have about 15 or 20 employees and now we want to use an administration software in the busines to do things like print parts prices, sales, income and so... you know the common things we need to get done.

What software do you recommend? Also, are there good free or open source? Please tell me if you have been working with one of those, how was the experience with it? Thanks guys!

Comment: Given that nobody knows exactly what it is your asking for, could you add some more information about the specific needs for that program? And since your asking for something free, is there a paid version that does the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not *exactly* sure what you're looking for, but [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/) seems to be a pretty good e-commerce software.  I apologize in advance if it's not what you had in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for but [Freshbooks](http://www.freshbooks.com/?ref=b17d1e4e145073-1) works great for us. It isn't free and isn't hosted internally but it does a great job and it has never let us down.